# MongoDB query for set of different categories

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

My Mongo database has a field which holds an array of strings, as follows:

```
db.band.insertMany([
   { name: "Alice", instrument: ["guitar", "voice"] },
   { name: "Bob", instrument: ["bass"] },
   { name: "Eve", instrument: ["drums", "voice"] }
]);
```

I would like to query the database to find the set of different instruments that can be played by the band members (in this example: `["guitar", "voice", "bass", "drums"]`).

Is it possible to do this with a simple query? I haven't been able to find anything related to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) to get document per instrument and then [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) with [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/index.html) to get unique values from all the documents:

```
db.band.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$instrument"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            instruments: { $addToSet: "$instrument" }
        }
    }
])
```

outputs:

```
{
    "_id": null,
    "instruments": [
        "drums",
        "bass",
        "voice",
        "guitar"
    ]
}
```